# Harddisk changes name - Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux

I just installed Archlinux, so I am very new to this.

When booting, it suddenly happens, that my SSD is not mounted as "sda" like when I installed Arch, but as "sdd" or "sdf". If this happens, my Arch doesn't boot.

I read that I shouldn't use this command to generate my fstab:

```
genfstab -Lp /mnt > /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Like it is proposed in the tutorial for installing arch.
I should use this

```
genfstab -Up /mnt > /mnt/etc/fstab
```

so that it is saved by UUID, so its unique.

But it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

My /etc/fstab:

```
# /dev/mapper/main-root LABEL=arch
UUID=35f1511b-d896-45eb-8a54-defc8356fa2a   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1

# /dev/sdd1 LABEL=boot
UUID=c71e37a9-e656-48bd-96e1-5ffd1904f542   /boot       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2

# /dev/mapper/main-home LABEL=home
UUID=509bb392-e5ba-4cdd-a10e-1017bc5fa736   /home       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2

# /dev/mapper/main-swap LABEL=swap
UUID=cc570380-9ef5-4304-96d7-3d50df41c21e   none        swap        defaults    0 0
```

This is the error-message, I get:
[image]

EDIT:
I don't get this Error when unplug my other harddisks where is Ubuntu and Windows installed.

My /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

http://pastebin.com/MDSNTRb4

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the current contents of your `/etc/fstab` file. Does it now contain UUIDs?

Comment: @terdon Yes it does, I checked that. I can't include it now, because I have not booted arch, since it doesn't work atm.

Comment: Well, we can't help you unless we know what's going on. If your fstab is using UUIDs, you wouldn't be getting messages about `sda` missing. Could you [edit] your question and include the current error message you get when attempting to boot?

Comment: @terdon I managed to boo arch, see my edit.

Comment: OK, that looks fine. Is there still a problem? If so, what error do you get?

Comment: @terdon Yes. I did a picture and added it.

Comment: Paste your boot {loader,manager} config...

Comment: @jasonwryan see my edit ;-)